# My html code doesn't get echo'ed out properly in my edit post form/

Tags: php, html, sql, database, echo

So, i've got an edit post form, and I have to select the content and title from the post with php, but when I do try to do that, the code doesn't work at all. Below is the code, and i've tried placing the whole code in an echo " ", still doesn't work.
I just can't find what the problem is here.

```
<?php
$sql_get = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id=$pid LIMIT 1";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_get);
if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0){
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
       $title = $row['title'];
       $content = $row['content'];



}
?>
     <form action='includes/edit_post.inc.php?pid=<?php echo "$pid";?>' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'> 
   <div class='input-group'>
       <label>Title</label>
   <input placeholder='Title' name='title' type='text' value='<?php echo "$title";?>' autofocus-size='48'><br /> <br /></div>
   <div class='input-group'>
    <label>Content</label></div>
   <div class='input-group'>
   <textarea placeholder='Content' name='content' rows='20' cols='50'><?php echo"$content";?></textarea><br /></div>
   <input name="update" type="submit" value="Update" class="btn">
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

I've chose placing the '$pid' into a input type hidden but still no results, maybe there is a problem in the other codes, i'll paste them below:

This is the new code with the input type hidden:

```
    <form action='includes/edit_post.inc.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'> 
      <input type='hidden' value='<?php $pid ?>';
    <div class='input-group'>
        <label>Title</label>
    <input placeholder='Title' name='title' type='text' value='<?php echo "$title";?>' autofocus-size='48'><br /> <br /></div>
    <div class='input-group'>
     <label>Content</label></div>
    <div class='input-group'>
    <textarea placeholder='Content' name='content' rows='20' cols='50'><?php echo"$content";?></textarea><br /></div>
    <input name="update" type="submit" value="Update" class="btn">
</form>
```

This is the edit_post.inc.php code:

```
<?php
session_start();
require'dbh.inc.php';
if(!isset($_SESSION['userId'])){
    header("Location: ../Login.php");
    return;}


if(isset($_POST['update'])){
    $title = strip_tags($_POST['title']);
    $content = strip_tags($_POST['content']);

      if(empty($title) || empty($content)) {

    echo 'Please complete your post!';
                return;
            }

            $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $title);
            $content = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $content);
            $date = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
            $sql = "UPDATE posts SET title='$title', content='$content', date='$date' WHERE id=$pid";

mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

header("Location:../Activities.php");



}

?>
```

Comment: Open generated html, what do you see there?

Comment: The html where i include the php parts just doesn't show at all on the website.

Comment: What i have above and below the php code shows up just fine.

Comment: Then enable error logging and check for any errors.

Comment: How do I do that? (Sorry i'm a beginner and don't know much)

Comment: Ok so i got this error : edit_post.php:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.

Comment: `value='<?php $pid ?>'` < that won't do anything. It's also unknown where you are assigning that variable.

Answer (score -1):

Your form path has a `GET` parameter and the method of form is `POST`. If you're really sure, that you want to do it via `GET` change the form method to `GET`. If you want to use use `POST` put the `$pid` as value in an input `type="hidden"`.

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = $pid LIMIT 1";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0){
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
       $title = $row['title'];
       $content = $row['content'];
   }
}

?>

<form action="includes/edit_post.inc.php?pid=<?php echo $pid; ?>" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
   <div class="input-group">
       <label>Title</label>
       <input placeholder="Title" name="title" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" autofocus-size="48"><br><br>
   </div>
   <div class="input-group">
       <label>Content</label>
   </div>
   <div class="input-group">
       <textarea placeholder="Content" name="content" rows="20" cols="50"><?php echo $content; ?></textarea>
   <br>
   </div>
   <input name="update" type="submit" value="Update" class="btn">
</form>
```

Comment: Add __explanation__ to your answer.

Comment: I edited the main post, where I included the edit_post.inc.php